# Import @types in typescript with yarn workspaces

Tags: typescript, types, yarn-workspaces

Consider a scenario where we have 2 workspaces.

## `workspace-a`

- `src/index.ts`

```js
import Exr from "./test.exr";

export const example = () => { 
  Exr;
};
```

- `src/test.exr`

```js
// binary file
```

- `src/@types/exr.d.ts`

```js
declare module "*.exr";
```

## `workspace-b`

- `src/index.ts`

```js
import { example } from "@project/workspace-a/src/index";

console.log(example());
```

When I run the command `tsc --noEmit` in `package-a` there is no problem. When I run it on `package-b` I get:

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module './test.exr' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import Exr from "./test.exr";
```

How to tell typescript to include @types when using local workspaces?